# Request-Response mechanism in Kaa

Tags: kaa

Is there any mechanism available in Kaa v 0.10.0 for querying the endpoints directly from Kaa server or any other application?

Let's say there is an application which can issue commands to devices and the device should process the command and send a response back to server/application.
The application will send such commands whenever it wishes and the Endpoint need to respond to this request.

Answer (score 0):

generally, Kaa has 2 mechanisms to work with endpoints (this may be direct application on your device or external application which controls device).

Endpoint-to-Endpoint communication can be established via [events](http://kaaproject.github.io/kaa/docs/v0.10.0/Programming-guide/Key-platform-features/Events/):  so it's up to your endpoint code to interpret it as request-response between them.

Kaa-to-Endpoint communication can be established via [notifications](http://kaaproject.github.io/kaa/docs/v0.10.0/Programming-guide/Key-platform-features/Notifications/):  but there is no way to make it bidirectional.

Also, another forms of interaction could be reached via EP profiles, EP groups, configurations. See platform features to get more information on this.

Comment: Does that mean we need to use a combination of events and notifications to have the request-response mechanism?
For ex. a web application that wants to send requests to a device and get the response back and then show it in UI.